# Checkmarx Jenkins plugin and CLI Binary install issues

Tags: jenkins, checkmarx, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to install the Checkmarx plugin into Jenkins (controller-agents) in a K8s cluster.
I've followed the documentation, but I'm getting this error despite the fact that I can successfully curl the GitHub and run other tasks.
The proxy setting have also been setup as environment variables.

```
Checkmarx Security tool could not be installed: api.github.com FATAL: Could not install Checkmarx CLI from binary java.net.UnknownHostException: api.github.com
```

**Jenkins version:** 2.414.2-lts-jdk17
**Checkmarx One Jenkins plugin:** v9.3.0
**Jenkins agent:** jenkins/inbound-agent:3160.vd76b_9ddd10cc-2-jdk11

I've setup a proxy in the tool section of Jenkins and made it available for the Jenkins plugin. In addition to be sure

Steps tried:

1. [Checkmarx One Documentation](https://checkmarx.com/resource/documents/en/34965-68685-checkmarx-one-jenkins-plugin.html)
2. [Checkmarx jenkins plugin doc](https://checkmarx.com/resource/documents/en/34965-8156-jenkins-plugin-overview.html)